# How to properly set up CSP in Tomcat 9.0.73 to ensure CSP header is visible in inspector?

Tags: tomcat9, content-security-policy

Set up CSP header in Tomcat version 9.0.73, but cannot see the CSP header

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src self ,imag src self">
```

How to solve the see the CSP header in inspector?

Answer (score 0):

You are adding CSP as a meta tag. This is allowed, but the common way of doing it is to add it as a response header. See https://csplite.com/csp341/ on how to add it as a response header in Tomcat.

Comment: i try to add filter in tomcat server, but the CSP header is only shown on json  page